# Qlik sense - Rank() within a specific dimension when you have multiple ones

Tags: ranking, rank, qlikview, qliksense

I am new to Qlik and trying to solve the following issue.

I have a table with two dimensions, one with the entry's unique ID, and one with a category, as in the example below.

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe3gw.png)

My goal is to create a new column with a ranking of 'Score' - my measure - per category:

[Table with desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQqK0.png)

If I use the expression

```
Rank(Score)
```

I get a column of ones, as the command takes the most granular dimension (Unique ID) as the default one. If I use

```
Rank(TOTAL Score)
```

It obviously returns a ranking regardless of all the dimensions. By reading the documentation and similar questions asked by other users I reckon that it should be possible to specify which dimension to use for TOTAL, with the following syntax:

```
Rank(TOTAL <Category> Score)
```

Yet, the formula returns an error and only null column values. I've tried different syntax, use of brackets but I still cannot grasp what I am doing wrong.

Please note that I cannot create the ranking column when loading the data.

I would immensely appreciate if someone were so kind to help on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
=aggr(rank(sum(Score)), Category, UniqueID)
```